# Is the Australian right-wing media giving Biden any credit for AUKUS?

Tags: media, australia, joe-biden, aukus

As far as I can tell from my limited sampling, the Murdoch-owned Australia press (e.g. Sky News Australia) is talking about Biden's mental capacity fairly constantly and not in a positive manner. It's the apparent lack of any change in discourse that I found intriguing. Roughly the same kind of segments were aired [in June](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoVQ6EihvTc) and at the [end of September](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUsFJmUQT8I), containing compilations of his verbal gaffes.

So, is the Australian right-wing media giving Biden any credit for AUKUS, or is that said as being mainly someone else's action/achievement in such venues?

Comment: Bit of of a push question here, Fizz.

Comment: @JamesK: why? I really don't know the answer. It could be that they're ignoring the subject, or paining Biden as a "useful idiot" skillfully manipulated by Morrison, or maybe that Trump set up the deal and Biden inherited it. I really have no idea.

Comment: It implies the Biden deserves credit, and that the right wing media is failing in not giving it to him.  You use loaded words like "harping" and "being spun",  these tend to give the impression that you question is "The Austrailian media should be giving credit to Biden.  Don't you agree".  That is the "push question" structure.

Comment: Perhaps a more neutral phrasing would be: 'how is Australian media portraying Biden's involvement in AUKUS and the recent nuclear submarine deal in particular?'

Comment: @JamesK you have edit privileges, you can use them to fix the question.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica I felt that an edit that would "fix" the question could contradict the author's intention.  Moreover, Fizz is a well known and respected user around here, one who understands well how the site works and one I trust to make an informed choice on fixing their own question.

Comment: @JamesK: it's fine to answer with a frame challenge that Biden doesn't deserve much/any credit, if that case can be made.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a push question to me; if it is so is any other question asking about a particular ideology's stance on a particular event.